# Tensorflow.js on node.js backend for speed increase warning deprecated?

Tags: javascript, node.js, tensorflow

I get this warning:

```
============================
Hi, looks like you are running TensorFlow.js in Node.js. To speed things up dram
atically, install our node backend, visit https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-nod
e for more details.
============================
```

I have this in my package.json

`"@tensorflow/tfjs": "^4.6.0",`

I only use cpu because my gpu doesnt have cuda.

The link in the warning seems deprecated.

Do you think I am actually using the best tensorflow for node.js or I can actually improve the speeds on the cpu?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, use this instead:

```
...
"@tensorflow/tfjs-node": "^4.7.0",
...
```

it'll be working faster also.